# how can I read sensors from an usb connected android device

Tags: java, android, tcp, usb, adb

I want to read sensor data from an android device which is connected via usb to a pc. Is there a way to read the sensor data through usb? Does getevent provide sensor values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With google's ADK one can transmit data easily via usb.
http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html